# How to click a button with its value with WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to click a button using a Perl script with the Mechanize module. However, the name and the position of the button always changes, so I want to click it by using its value, but I could not find how to do it.

The button is like this:

```html
<input class="submit good" name="R_HCWE" value="CLICK HERE" type="submit">
```

I cannot use simply the `submit()` method, because there is another button to submit the form that belongs to class "submit bad".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `find_all_submits` method to find the button, then click it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = 'WWW::Mechanize'->new;
$mech->get('http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize');
$mech->update_html(<< '__HTML__');

<html>
<body>
<form action="/1.pl">
<input class="submit bad" name="R_ACWE" value="DO NOT CLICK HERE" type="submit">
<input class="submit good" name="R_HCWE" value="CLICK HERE" type="submit">
<form>
</body>
</html>

__HTML__

my $button = ($mech->find_all_submits(class => 'submit good'))[0];
say $button->class;
```

Comment: hello ,  $input just returns me number of buttons belong to this class .  When I print it , it displays 1

Comment: I apologize to ask question again , but in the website , the button always change the position , so sometimes I click the right button , but sometimes the wrong one , I tried $mech->find_all_submits(value => 'CLICK HERE'))[0]; too , but did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Are the other buttons also `submit good` classified?

Comment: I have this <input class="submit good" name="R_HCWE" value="CLICK HERE" type="submit">   , and this <input class="submit bad" name="R_ACWE" value="DO NOT CLICK HERE" type="submit"> , did not work means my script clicks one of these two buttons just randomly , because the position of the buttons always changes , and it clicks the first one.

Comment: @ccca: How can it return all the inputs when you specify the class?

Comment: I did not get what I am doing wrong , is it possible to read the text that the button has?

Comment: @ccca: I updated the post with a standalone example that works. You can switch the buttons and it would still work.